# Android device doesnt receive push

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Cannot receive push.

Preconditions:

1) AndroidManifest properly configured (permissions, user-permissions, service, broadcastreceiver with correct intent-filter)

2) in developer console created credentials for android app and server.

My steps:

1) register device:

```
if (mGCM == null) {
   mGCM = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(mContext);
}
mRegId = mGCM.register(Constants.SENDER_ID);
```

2) send mRegId to server

3) server send push to device. Google answer is:

```
{"multicast_id":7343763038953489252,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1428566852416853%a96fd634f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

Result: no push in `GcmBroadcastReceiver`

Comment: have you enable Google Push Notification For Android API from google console ?

Comment: what result do you get when you send the push from your server?

Comment: @HareshChhelana of cause, see my second precondition.

Comment: @giorashc see my 3rd step. Server result is OK. but nothing happens

Comment: @AlexKlimashevsky,I'm talking about enable GCM for android  API in API ACCESS menu in old google console and Permission in new google console.

Comment: post your code and manifest please

Comment: Does this happen on multiple Android devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I regenerated api key for android. Also merge together keys for debug and releases.

Answer (score 0):

1. On which device you are testing ? If it is pre 4.0.4 then you must be logged in with some google account. See for reference : [Why google Account login is required for GCM to work for devices below 4.0.4 OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25498608/why-google-account-login-is-required-for-gcm-to-work-for-devices-below-4-0-4-os)
2. Also check if have google play services installed on the device.
3. Check in android manifest if the app package is same as in broadcast receiver you have registered.

PS: Assuming you have registered broadcast correctly .