# Device Registration Id/Device Token is not generating

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-devicetoken

I am trying to work with GCM(Google Cloud Messaging) for Push Notification, i have tried with sample application it's working fine with my device and Device Id/Token is generating and able to push notification.

If i try the same application with another device application is running but Device Token/Registration id is not getting generated.

I don't know where i'm making mistake need help to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my code snippet

```
 public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    final String preferences = getString(R.string.preferences);
    savedValues = getSharedPreferences(preferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // In later versions multi_process is no longer the default
    if(VERSION.SDK_INT >  9){
        savedValues = getSharedPreferences(preferences, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
    }
    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getBaseContext());
    SharedPreferences savedValues = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if(savedValues.getBoolean(getString(R.string.first_launch), true)){
        register();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = savedValues.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.first_launch), false);
        editor.commit();
    }
    // Let AndroidMobilePushApp know we have just initialized and there may be stored messages
    sendToApp(new Bundle(), this);
}
```

and then my register method,

```
private void register() {
    new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>(){
        protected Object doInBackground(final Object... params) {
            String token;
            try {
                token = gcm.register(getString(R.string.project_number));
                Log.i("registrationId", token);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i("Registration Error", e.getMessage());
            }
            return true;
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: It would be good if you share your code to get Device ID. and Device name on which the Device Token is not generating.

Comment: Please can you add your gcm register code?

Comment: Hope the above snippets helps...!

Comment: I am assuming that you are able to go through the try-catch portion without throwing an exception. Check that `R.string.project_number` returns a valid value on your test device.

Answer (score 0):

1. On which device you are testing ? If it is pre 4.0.4 then you must be logged in with some google account. See for reference : [Why google Account login is required for GCM to work for devices below 4.0.4 OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25498608/why-google-account-login-is-required-for-gcm-to-work-for-devices-below-4-0-4-os)
2. Also check if have google play services installed on the device.
3. Check in android manifest if the app package is same as in broadcast receiver you have registered.