# GET_ACCOUNTS permission dangerous?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to update my application to support v23 properly especially in terms of the new permission model. Unfortunately I'm kinda confused when it comes to the `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission. According to [Table 1 (Dangerous permissions and permission groups)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#perm-groups) the GET_ACCOUNTS permission is classified as dangerous though when you look at the [Manifest.permission docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_ACCOUNTS) the Protection Level is set to normal which basically means that I don't need to request the permission from the user.
I've looked at the App Info -> Permissions page and the contacts permission can be revoked which seems to indicate that it is indeed a dangerous permission.

So basically the questions are:

- Is it really a dangerous permission?
- Is this permission required for GCM if my app is targeting only API-Level 14 and higher? [(seems like this isn't the case)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18444343/4126219)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the permission is dangerous since dp3. And no with the latest Google play services, this permission is not needed to use GCM.

Comment: I am developing an app in the rage API 9 to API 23. Then is there need the permission  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />   on manifest file?

Comment: @VinilChandran What's changed is in Google Play Services, so no problem even if you're targeting API 9, as long as you're using the recent Play Services version.